# How to change my background?

Tags: desktop-background

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 (my system info reads "Ubuntu 13.04", though, for some reason).

Right clicking on the Desktop and then changing the background there doesnt work and just sends me to System Settings. I installed `Wallach` to change the background, but I'd prefer a "proper" solution.

What am I doing wrong, or how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you *sure* you're running 12.10? There is no reason for 12.10 to read 13.04 ever, and if you are running 13.04, this may well be a bug related to Ubuntu+1, which [is inappropriate here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if it shows `Ubuntu 13.04` you're using a non-stable version of Ubuntu, what you shouldn't be doing if this is your work machine because this versions can contain bugs.

Furthermore, in `System Settings` there is the option `Appearance`, where you can change the background for an image in a set of standard images or for an image in your computer.

Comment: in system settinings I dont have Appearance options and about 13.04 i dont know when it update to this, I know it unstable and maybe its a problem... How can i downgrade ubuntu and save all stuff?

Comment: I've seen this "13.04" report from other users as well recently. Seems innocent and just a minor bug.

Comment: You could try `sudo apt get update` en after that `sudo do-release-upgrade`